# Does LIRS store a boundless number of elements?

Tags: caching

I'm looking into implementing LIRS caching algorithm (as described in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIRS_caching_algorithm) and [this paper](http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/hpcs/WWW/HTML/publications/papers/TR-02-6.pdf)), but the sources are rather difficult to follow, leaving out certain cases from their descriptions. Referring to [example (e) on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIRS_caching_algorithm#Selecting_the_replacement_victim) where a previously unknown element is referenced, it appears the element is added as resident HIR, without any element being deleted from LIRS. This suggests I could keep referencing unique elements, and grow LIRS forever. Is this the case...? This seems bad, as the references could blow up the using application's memory. Am I missing something?

Also, if anyone knows any interesting alternatives to LIRS that are well described, I'd love to know about them - doing some side programming to catch up on my C++, and caching is the topic I've been working on :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the two paper do not mention an explicit bound. However, the authors kindly provided me their simulator and it has a [bound parameter](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/blob/master/simulator/src/main/resources/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/simulator/parser/lirs/lirs.h#L8). Many implementations have had memory leaks (e.g. [Clojure's](https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CCACHE-32), [Infinispan](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-7171?_sscc=t)).

Unfortunately naive pruning is expensive as it requires a long stack walk. Thomas Mueller's [implementation](https://github.com/apache/jackrabbit-oak/blob/trunk/oak-core-spi/src/main/java/org/apache/jackrabbit/oak/cache/CacheLIRS.java) uses a secondary queue for non-resident entries. This adds a little more cost per entry, but significantly improves runtime performance in my benchmarks.

Unfortunately none of the implementations I came across matched the author's simulator. This is because some details are easily missed (like warmup) or not mentioned (don't promote on a correlated references). After debugging traces against their simulator, [mine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/blob/master/simulator/src/main/java/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/simulator/policy/irr/LirsPolicy.java) is near perfect and includes Thomas' optimization. It was intended to be accurate and readable in case I adopted it for a cache.

I chose [TinyLFU](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.00727.pdf) instead, after introducing an admission window to improve its performance in recency-skewed traces. The authors and I are experimenting with an adaptive window based on simple hill climbing to replace the static configuration. This [article](http://highscalability.com/blog/2016/1/25/design-of-a-modern-cache.html), [slides](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1NlDxyXsUG1qlVHMl4vsUUBQfAJ2c2NsFPNPr2qymIBs), and [simulations](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Efficiency) should provide a brief introduction to the policy. A reader implemented a minimal [C++ port](https://github.com/mandreyel/w-tiny-lfu).

Answer (score 0):

LIRS allows some "ghost items". Ghost items are items whose values no longer exist in memory, however, theirs keys exist in LIRS stack. So that although these ghosts are gone, we can still calculate their IRR and Recency, in case they are accessed again.

> Referring to example (e) on wikipedia where a previously unknown element is referenced, it appears the element is added as resident HIR, without any element being deleted from LIRS.

In this example, when `C` is accessed, it replaces `E`, and saved in both LIR stack and HIR queue. Although `E` still exists in LIR stack, its status has been changed to non-resident HIR page, which means `E`'s value has been removed from cache, while its key still exists.

You can check [this C++ implementation](https://github.com/sewenew/cache/blob/main/src/sw/cache/lirs_cache.h) for detail.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of [this project](https://github.com/sewenew/cache).

Comment: Thanks :) Been quite a while since I'd looked into this; I was actually also doing this for a little caching library for my own amusement, if you were curious https://github.com/rollie42/Cache/tree/master/Cache/lib